# Make particles bounce off of each other

Tags: particles

I am making a scene where I have balls pouring into a invisible container. The problem is these balls pass through each other which makes it unrealistic. I have tried searching for the 'Molecular Addon' by Pyroevil but it seems the website no longer exists. PLease help Thank you very much

[image]

to all those suggesting and giving me links to pyroevil I have told you it's not working for me all i see is this.

[image]

Comment: The molecular add-on is at this link: http://pyroevil.com/category/scripts-addons/molecular-script/

Comment: That's strange.. You can still find [the docs etc. on the internet archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20161026013118/http://pyroevil.com/category/scripts-addons/molecular-script/), and the [addon itself is on github](https://github.com/Pyroevil/Blender-Molecular-Script).

Comment: Sadly I don't have time to give a full answer, but have you tried collision modifiers (for your particles)?  Another way of achieving this used to be possible as well with the game engine.  You could let the game engine figure out all the collisions and then record it.

Comment: THANK YOU for the answers. I have found a way to solve my problem. :)

Comment: @Blenderino If you've solved your problem could you please submit an answer with the details so that others can also benefit from your solution.

Comment: To prevent particles overlapping you might want to consider this answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/84426/29586

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80690/random-sized-cylinders-with-no-intersection-gaps