# Why half of those particles (red balls) going through the collision (white plane)?

Tags: particles

[image]

The particles are falling on the collision but half of them are upside the collision and half are down the collision plane.

Comment: Could you show the particle size of this particle system in the 3D viewport? It's under the Display section.

Answer (score 1):

Particles are not objects in blender, they do not have a geometry, even if you attach an object to them, the geometry is not simulated physically with the particle system.

The spheres will always intersect the plane as long as the particle is flush on it.

If you want your particles to be physical, you need the Molecular addon: http://pyroevil.com/category/scripts-addons/molecular-script/

Alternatively you would need to run a physics simulation using rigid bodies.

Or in this case the collision margin of the plane needs to be the -radius- of the red sphere. Note that this will still make the red spheres intersect each other since theres no way to stop that from occurring with the vanilla particle system.

Comment: It is possible to get the particles to repel each other using Self Effect force - see https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/84426/29586

Comment: Thats a really bad workaround as the particles will never settle.

Comment: I know - but it’s a quick and dirty method of preventing them intersecting. Molecular addon is far superior - especially if you want to fill a container - but far more complicated. Using Self Effect is enough if you only have sparsely packed particles (as in the example in the original question).