# Is there anyway to make particles have an influence area around them that will let them collide, without having to turn them into rigid bodies?

Tags: particles, physics, collision

I want to make a particle simulation, however, is there any way to set a sphere as a child and then set an "influence radius" around each particle as like a collision box? I know you can set them to rigid bodies but that really slows down the simulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a force to the particles to effectively repel each other as in this answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/84426/29586. It isn’t ideal as it relies on the particles being all the same size and it isn’t physically accurate (but is a quick and dirty method).

Another option is to use the Molecular Script add-on (http://pyroevil.com/molecular-script-docs/) which physically simulates the particle collisions.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I was thinking of adding a force but not sure how well it worked, also I tried the molecular script and I followed a tutorial and it just didn't seem to work. I thought it was because I downloaded the one for blender 2.77 which was the most recent one that I found

Comment: Opp nevermind, the reason it wasn't working with the molecular was because, instead of editing the particles' size, I was editing their draw size, my bad, thanks for the reply! :D