# How to fill container with granular material?

Tags: particles

Recently I've been trying to create a simulation of the Zeer Pot system, which essentially consists of a pot filled with sand. So, how can I generate sand particles in order to fill a container? Note that, preferably, the particles should have a mesh shape to give accuracy or precision to the simulation.

Comment: If you can at all avoid it, don't use particles for sand. Use a texture, or a volume. If you're dead set on particles, you can emit them from the volume of your container, and crank up the amount a lot.

Comment: This question might help - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76614/fill-particles-in-a-container#84426