# How can I distribute various objects based on their size?

Tags: workflow

Are there any techniques or tools in Blender to help make an image like this?

[image]

There are a few things in this image that I'm specifically interested in:

1. size: big objects at the top, small objects at the bottom
2. density: distribution is less dense near the middle-bottom
3. packing: there are small stones packed amongst the big stones at the top
4. collision: there doesn't appear to be any stone/stone overlaps

Comment: Still Image or Dynamic?

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger still image is fine. I just edited my question which hopefully clarifies what I'm trying to do

Comment: Blender has no dynamic modeling built-in. 1, 2 and 3 can be done with cycles particle system. #4 may be done with the animation nodes addon, which can measure distance between particles..

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: This is not a true way of sorting by size, just a way of faking it by scaling objects.

[image]

This works by using a vertex group to affect the particle size and density, simply create a gradient to affect particle size as desired

Start by creating a circular mesh, a cobweb like topology will likely help.

[image]

Add a new vertex group and use *Weight Paint* mode to paint in in a gradient shape to your liking.

[image]

Create new particle system set to *Hair* type, and use the previously created *Vertex Group* to drive both its Density and Length parameters.

[image]

[image]

Comment: One of the things I really like about the reference image I posted is how there are small objects packed around the large objects to make for a really dense layout, without having any object overlap. Is there any way to achieve that with this method?

Comment: Not directly no, but you could convert the particles into real objects afterwards, add rigid body properties then drop them with a physics simulation. That should make a non intersecting distribution roughly respecting the already obtained gradient. This may help https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80690/random-sized-cylinders-with-no-intersection-gaps/80721#80721

Answer (score -2):

- 2 or More Particle Systems emitted from a circular mesh.
- 2 or More Physics Systems Baked
- Image compositing