# How would you go about creating shards of glass?

Tags: modeling, materials, light

I need to cover a large area with shards of glas
like in this picture.

[image]

The shards look like this:
[image]

My idea was to maybe sculpt the whole pile.
And then use a clever material, to create the individual pieces of glas and their reflections
.
But i have no idea how and if this would work.
Especially since the camera moves around the scene.

Any ideas on how to do this are well appreciated :)

Comment: Sounds like the job for a [particle system](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86844/how-can-i-distribute-various-objects-based-on-their-size)

Comment: You know, blenderguru has a great tutorial on that! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9L8qOq1Shiw

Comment: I was hoping for something without particles,  cause thats a loooot of particles that i need.