# How to make a model latte art shaped like logo

Tags: modeling, particles

I need to make a latte art in shape of a already made 2D logo in greyscale. Dont want to paste a texture on coffee surface, need to be a 3D model. Tried to do that using weight-painting, but hand drawing is way to inprecise.

Comment: It sounds as if  deriving some form of vector graphics, or curves within Blender, from your greyscale image would be your best starting point for creating a model. (You can then also use appropriate orthographic renders of the model as the basis of your various specular/bump/displacement...etc maps for the finished result.)  If possible, could you show us the greyscale reference?

Comment: Distorting froth will be hard, I suggest using a micro displacement texture that is modified by hacking the normal values. I think that the white bubbles are smaller than the brown ones. Also the white froth appears that way due to the subsurface scattering of milk so I would texture then SSS

Comment: here is the logo https://image.ibb.co/kg1y0H/2.png
being a beginner in 3D modelling im doing most of things done watching tutorials. i found one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4rNrL7a12xg with acceptable results, but i cant find a way to use already made image for weight painting

Comment: Maybe this technique can nudge you in the right way https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86844/how-can-i-distribute-various-objects-based-on-their-size