# How to achieve random distance, rotation between copies with array and curve modifier?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I'm doing a crown, and I put the thorns on the stem with an array and curve modifier. I'd like to have the thorns to have non uniform distance and rotation around the stem.

[image]

How can this be achieved?

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Array Modifier is good at uniformity, if you want randomness use a particle system instead

Comment: Can you elaborate how? @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I've tried with particle system with no luck. Maybe I did something wrong

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57360/would-this-spiky-hair-be-doable-using-particles-system/57362#57362 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/113973/place-spawn-objects-along-curve-with-randomized-scale-and-rotation/113989#113989 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86844/how-can-i-distribute-various-objects-based-on-their-size/86850#86850

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Cheers mate!

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I've tried with the particle system, I could manage to have the particles to follow the curve, but it seems it does not have any effect on the position of the thorns, it is still going with the array order. The particles are just hanging around the duplicated objects proximity. See picture
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos OK I realised I can't have a particle system assigned to a bezier curve, I have a mesh plus a particle instance, BUT I only see the proper setup of my objects spreaded out according to the particle positions in EDIT mode only, when I'm on object mode it is a mess. It is a bug?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I forgot to disable the array modifier, however the overall result is far from optimal with the particle modifier. The thorns are not aligned to the normals of the faces, and I couldn't really find the way to set the proper position of the copied thorns relative to the particle position. And because it's only working with a mesh and not with a curve, In the end I find the original curve/array method a more suitable execution, well at least in this case. The only downside is the slight deformation of some thorns, which I still have to figure how to get rid of.