# How to fit "n" identical objects in a circle?

Tags: python, modeling, modifiers

I have to fit some n identical cylinders in a circular cross-section of diameter D. I was trying to use the array modifier but that seems to work for duplicating on the curve and not inside the curve. Is there any way to achieve it from the GUI or any other alternative way using python?[image: I have to fill the entire circle with unit present at the center.]

[image: This is to be multiplied throughout to fill the bigger circle.]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80690/random-sized-cylinders-with-no-intersection-gaps

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I need to arrange the cylinders in a definite order. A definite number of cylinders arranged linearly along the diameter, then decreasing continuously to complete the circle.

Comment: [Circle Packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle) I recall a question about it here, can't find it.  Have a look at the wonderful [sverchok addon](https://plus.google.com/+TorolfSauermann/posts/GirWVKHMj6h)

Comment: By a 'Definite Order', do you mean in a definite sequence, or just a definite arrangement? Do you want, for example, [triangular packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing) on a hexagonal lattice?

Comment: @RobinBetts I am looking for triangular packing on a hexagonal lattice only. By definite order I mean the arrangement is fixed.

Comment: As @batFINGER points out with his link, while you can pack a hexagon easily enough with a triangular grid, optimally packing a circle with circles is a mathematically hard problem to which there is no regular solution. Maybe there's a regular (rule-based) sub-optimal solution you are looking for?

Comment: I am completely new to blender, considering that can you help me in this? What I am thinking of is, if possible I can fit hexagons in the circle and then at each vertex as the center, I can place the circle.@RobinBetts

Comment: not sure what you mean, can help only with sverchok addon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=49632
HERE is solution with maybe many of circles
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please use [here](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) for blend files. The paste all file will be automatically removed after a certain time, making the answer less useful in future.

Comment: Don't use Pasteall.org to host files. The links expire after a while and then no one will be able to download them, making your the answer less useful. Don't make the answer depend on the user reverse-engineer your file, to make the answer clear, please expand the text and add an explanation of what you are doing. The images are not enough to understand the logic of your nodes or why you chose the values you are using.

Comment: I am not able to understand your logic, can you elaborate a bit, considering I am new to the software.

Comment: There is monad (group) of sverchok that contain nodes (select and press tab or alt+G to ungroup) and see what inside. i just filter vertices incoming