# Is there any way to export the last frame of a physics simulation from command line?

Tags: python, mesh, export, physics

I have a basic rigid body physics sim, but I want to export the last frame of the simulation. So far I have tried setting the "current frame to the last frame of the simulation and exporting it that way, but that doesn't work.

```
#Select all objects other than the suitcase
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.data.objects['Suitcase'].select = False

# store the location of current 3d cursor
saved_location = bpy.context.scene.cursor_location.copy()  # returns a copy of the vector

# give 3dcursor new coordinates
bpy.context.scene.cursor_location = (0.0,0.0,0.0)

# set the origin on the current object to the 3dcursor location
bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CURSOR')
bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CENTER_OF_VOLUME')

# Randomly place objects in the air    
bpy.ops.object.randomize_transform(random_seed= randint(1,9000), use_delta=False, use_loc=True, loc=(12.0, 8.0, 0.0), use_rot=True, rot=(360.0, 360.0, 360.0), use_scale=False, scale_even=False, scale=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')

#Runs physics simulation
bpy.context.scene.frame_set(1)
bpy.context.scene.frame_current += 1
bpy.context.scene.update()
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.visual_transform_apply()

# Define Directory
dir = bpy.path.abspath('//stlexport/')

# Create Directory (If Necessary)
if not os.path.exists(dir): os.makedirs(dir)

# Export STLs
bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl(filepath = dir, batch_mode = 'OBJECT')
```

Comment: I want to run this out of the command line so I can run a batch file to automate the process multiple times

Comment: Please provide some details re: script (even if it _"doesn't work"_) and cli call.

Comment: This script exports only the location of the objects on the first frame, it doesn't update their position when I change frames

Comment: AFAIK `scene.frame_set` sets the current frame and also updates the scene.   Does last frame export work from UI?  If not add the operator described by @Duarte below before export.

Comment: I have tried both, suggestions and neither exports the last frame of the animation. Would I need to bake the animation through the command line as well? PS: I have no idea what baking accomplishes, I am very new to blender animation

Comment: As in it doesn't export properly from UI either? btw if 250 is last frame of animation using `scene.frame_set(250)` might help.  As mentioned earlier, don't need to set `frame_current` (and maybe not update either)

Comment: I have tried that as well, and yes, it does not export from UI either

Answer (score 3):

**Bake the point cache**

Using same method as with particles here [CLI How to render last frame of hair dynamics sym?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146811/cli-how-to-render-last-frame-of-hair-dynamics-sym)

Replace "runs physics simulation" with a bake operator below. Not sure if playing, or frame setting, and baking happen in bg mode as they do when using GUI.

`rbw.py`

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context

scene = context.scene
rbw = scene.rigidbody_world
pc = rbw.point_cache

# match bake to animation
print(pc.frame_start, pc.frame_end)


bpy.ops.ptcache.bake({"point_cache": pc}, bake=True)

scene.frame_set(250)
bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(filepath="test.obj")
```

Testing in CLI with

```
blender -b xxx.blend -P rbw.py
```

can confirm  `test.obj` is a result of simple physics sim at 250.

Comment: @RobinBetts re comment on DRF's answer below, spit-balling,  export frame n-r to n and flick the animated switch.