# Build a pile of boxes

Tags: objects

I think what i'm looking for is the answer to a chronic problem with Blender but i thought i'd ask before giving up.

I simply want to build a random/chaotic pile of various boxes on a floor plane.  I've tried:

- particles but they don't interact (pile up)
- dropping groups of boxes on a floor using rigid body physics - great for the first heap but fixing in that in place ready to drop the next heap on top is so convoluted and doesn't seem reliable (removing the RigidBodyWorld group and rebuilding it each time would seem to be the solution but clumps of boxes return to their pre-drop position seemingly at random); and,
- i've bought an add-on called MassFX that purports to drop random batches of objects on top of one another but it's horribly unstable and very lacking in documentation

So, if anyone has any suggestions for an approach.  I'd really appreciate your help/ideas while i still have some hair to tear out!

Thanks

Stephen

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80690/random-sized-cylinders-with-no-intersection-gaps

Comment: Thanks Duarte.  The response you signposted didn't really solve my problem until I dug deeper and found the golden nugget - Apply Visual Transforms!  Eureeka!  This fixes rigid body objects at the end of a simulation allowing the process to be re-run and more objects piled on top.  Still a manual process but one that works!  How does anyone find these little gems?  Thank you thank you

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112029/is-there-any-way-to-export-the-last-frame-of-a-physics-simulation-from-command-l/