# CLI How to render last frame of hair dynamics sym?

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine

I have a script that generates random hair 
I want it to play animation from 1st frame to 250th, and then output a rendered image of 250th frame, or simply give me the 250th frame without playing animation (that would a be better option)

Here's my code to play animation:

```
# Animation Frame Timer
def stop_playback(scene):
    if scene.frame_current == 250:
        bpy.ops.screen.animation_cancel(restore_frame=False)

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(stop_playback)
bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()

bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].frame_set(250)
```

I have 2 scripts. One for generating hair, and one for rendering my output image.
I use this command in terminal to execute it:

```
#!/bin/bash
frames_cnt=#needed number of images
output_frame_path='BlenderRepository/RenderedImages/LongHair'

for (( i=1; i<=frames_cnt; i++ )); do
  echo "Rendering frame ${i}/${frames_cnt}..."

  (
    cd /home/ds/Documents/blender2.80/
    ./blender --background una.blend --python BlenderRepository/Scripts/Config/LongHair/LongHair.py --python BlenderRepository/Scripts/Config/LongHair/RenderLongHairImage.py -- "${output_frame_path}/frame_${i}.png"
  )

  echo "Frame ${i}/${frames_cnt} has been rendered"
done
```

When I executing my script via terminal, I suppose it gives me the 1st frame as output. Well, formally its 250th frame, but it looks like 1st frame, as you can see here:
[image]

And here's example when I manually execute my scripts via blender one by one:
[image]

You can see that the animation has been played, and its 250th frame, as hair lay down. I executed my 1st script for generating hair, wait for animation to run from 1 to 250th frame, and then executed the 2nd script.

So my question is how can I make it work automatically? Is it possible to make it work that way in the --background? I mean I want my second script wait for 1st script to end animation run, so I can get the right image of 250th frame.

2 Particle Systems code:

```
psys = ob.particle_systems[-1]
psys1 = ob.particle_systems[-1]

pc = psys.point_cache
pc1 = psys1.point_cache

print(pc.frame_start, pc.frame_end)

bpy.ops.ptcache.bake({"point_cache": pc}, bake=True)
bpy.ops.ptcache.bake({"point_cache": pc1}, bake=True)
```

Comment: Have you tested to see if blender in background mode bakes the simulation as animation is played. _which it appears is what you are relying on here_  I would recommend looking at the cache panel.  Try bake the animation, then render.  Notice after a bake the button is toggled to "free bake", see if using the same logic the draw uses works with your script... else maybe bake n save. Then render.

Comment: @batFINGER I've never used bake animation before, gonna give it a try now

Comment: @batFINGER could you please tell me how do I test to see if blender in background mode bakes the simulation as animation is played? and how do I bake the animation in blender 2.8?

Comment: Added a script to bake point cache as an answer, too long to comment.  Use it instead of the play stop script. Match the point cache frame start and end to scene.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Bake the [`Pointcache`](https://docs.blender.org/api/master/bpy.types.PointCache.html#module-bpy.types)**

Here is a test script that bakes the first particle system on context object to first point cache.

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context

ob = context.object
# assume we have a particle system
ps = ob.particle_systems[0]
pc = ps.point_cache

# match bake to animation
print(pc.frame_start, pc.frame_end)

bpy.ops.ptcache.bake({"point_cache": pc}, bake=True)
```

Have a look at the [`PointCache`](https://docs.blender.org/api/master/bpy.types.PointCache.html#module-bpy.types) members in the API, and will see that among others it has

```
pc.is_baking
pc.is_baked
```

Now to test this in bg mode.

**Confirmation**

Can confirm that, with script above named `test.py` the command *blender2.8 is an alias to my blender version 2.8*

```
blender2.8 -b test.blend -P test.py -f 250
```

when run on blend that is no more than  default cube, with default hair particle system, (with dynamics) produces following output

```
Read blend: /home/batfinger/blender/test/test.blend
1 250
bake: frame 1 :: 250
bake: frame 2 :: 250
bake: frame 3 :: 250
bake: frame 4 :: 250 
...


bake: frame 248 :: 250
bake: frame 249 :: 250
bake: frame 250 :: 250
Fra:250 Mem:182.13M (0.00M, Peak 183.09M) | Time:00:00.33 | Syncing Cube
Fra:250 Mem:182.17M (0.00M, Peak 183.09M) | Time:00:00.38 | Syncing Lamp
Fra:250 Mem:182.17M (0.00M, Peak 183.09M) | Time:00:00.38 | Syncing Camera
Fra:250 Mem:182.18M (0.00M, Peak 183.09M) | Time:00:00.41 | Rendering 1 / 64 samples
Fra:250 Mem:182.17M (0.00M, Peak 183.09M) | Time:00:00.77 | Rendering 26 / 64 samples
Fra:250 Mem:182.17M (0.00M, Peak 183.09M) | Time:00:00.97 | Rendering 51 / 64 samples
Fra:250 Mem:182.17M (0.00M, Peak 183.09M) | Time:00:01.07 | Rendering 64 / 64 samples
Fra:250 Mem:124.26M (0.00M, Peak 183.09M) | Time:00:01.30 | Sce: Scene Ve:0 Fa:0 La:0
Saved: '/tmp/0250.png'
 Time: 00:02.24 (Saving: 00:00.94)
```

[image]
*`/tmp/0250.png`*

Comment: Gonna try it now, thanks @batFINGER

Comment: It works indeed, thanks a lot for help!!! @batFINGER

Comment: Cheers. Please consider editing  title of question to something like _"CLI How to render last frame of hair dynamics sym"_ or the like.

Comment: also is there a way to bake animation for two particle systems? as I use 2. It perfectly works now, but I'm just wondering if there's a way to catalyze this process as it runs 1 to 250 two times. I add my edition of your code to the bottom of my question, so you can look at it @batFINGER

Comment: Have a look at the bake all button.

Comment: bpy.ops.ptcache.bake_all(bake=True) doesnt work for me @batFINGER

Comment: Not sure, but if each frame of a bake takes about the same time, for say  10 ps's over 100 frames not going to matter if we loop 100 x 10 or 10 x 100.  Time it on a simple test case, playing animation to bake via ui, or baking 10 sequentially via CLI.