# Blender 2.83 Python API - smoke not rendering EEVEE

Tags: python, rendering, eevee-render-engine

As per title. Minimal code example is:

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='FLUID')
bpy.ops.object.material_slot_add()
bpy.ops.object.quick_smoke()
bpy.context.scene.frame_end = 10
bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True)
```

Interestingly, if I do `bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()`, let it finish and then `bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True)`, the smoke renders correctly!

Tested on both Mac and Windows.

Comment: Imagine this is similar Run the bake operator for smoke.. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112029/is-there-any-way-to-export-the-last-frame-of-a-physics-simulation-from-command-l  As mentioned Playing the animation first also bakes.

Comment: Yes, baking was the answer - I knew `animation_play()` must have been doing something extra. Adding `bpy.ops.fluid.bake_data()` before `bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True)` solved it!