# Fill the volume area of one mesh with another mesh

Tags: modifiers, particles, rigidbody

I would like to know if it is possible to fill a mesh, using it as a bounds area to then fill it entirely with a polygon(the shape) mesh.

The idea is I’ve blocked out a level design. But i want my level to be all polygons just like Vavle’s the lab archery level.

[image]

I have made various block sections of the level and now want to make it look like the section is made up of multiple individual polygon meshes. So I want them all touching but would still like to modify them individually. For example I am wanting to add details to the outside polygons

Edit: linked solution doesn't work for a hexagon. The rigidbodies never settle in the animation.

[image: rigidbodies]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80690/random-sized-cylinders-with-no-intersection-gaps

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks, seems like the solution I am after.  ah do I mark this as a duplicate? Or do you need to submit a correct answer and I will mark it as solved.

Comment: @cgslav do I need to ask a new question?