# Fill the volume area of a bounding box with a grouping of individual meshes

Tags: modifiers, rigidbody

I asked how to fill a volumn area with a hexagon. over here: [Fill the volume area of one mesh with another mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/117261/39530)

This was marked as a duplicate, and pointed to a solution.
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/80721/39530
I edited my question to reflect the original solution didn't work for me.

Proposed solution doesn't work for a hexagon. The rigidbodies never settle in the animation.

[image: rigidbodies]

So I am asking again as the edited question that it is marked as duplicate isn't being viewed.

I would like to know if it is possible to fill a mesh, using it as a bounds area to then fill it entirely with a polygon(the shape) mesh.

The idea is I’ve blocked out a level design. But i want my level to be all hexagons(the shape) just like Vavle’s the lab archery level.

[image: vr lab archery]

I have made various block sections of the level and now want to make it look like the section is made up of multiple individual hexagon meshes. So I want them all touching but would still like to modify them individually. For example I am wanting to add details to the outside hexagon meshes.

So if the rigidbody doesn't work, is there a rubber stamp solution? I would make a group of hexagons stamp them in a area. I would want each mesh to snap edges to a its neighbor if it's the same type of object.

Comment: Try adding a particle emitter. Start and end set to 1. Render: Object and select your hexagon.  Emit from Volume: Grid: Hexagonal Grid. Then under the Modifiers tab Convert to make particles real. You may have to fiddle with the Emitter resolution and Render Object Size, but a quick test showed it was possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to use the particle emitter to create hexagonal fills.

Create a **Cylinder** with 6 sides as your Hexagon and define a **Plane** as the level shape. (I did try this with a 3D mesh but it is a bit more tricky to get everything lined up).
[image]

Add an **Emitter** and set the **Object** to be your **Cylinder** and the size to **0.5**
[image]

Set the **Emitter End** to **1**(so everything is done in frame 1) the **Emit From** to **Faces** and **Grid**, then you can check the box **Hexagonal Grid**. The **Resolution** needs to be tweaked here to get the fit of hexagons correct.

[image]

Then on the **Modifiers** panel click **Convert** to make the particles real.
[image]

and you can delete the original **Plane** and source **Cylinder** and manipulate the individual Cylinders.

[image]

[image]

Comment: One thing that I can't figure out. How to then select only a handful cylinders and modify them? in edit mode I can edit all but not only 1 (or selected a few) in object mode I can select a handful but only the 1st item is modified.  I'm trying to scale in this case. I have hit convert, is there something else to make them behave like a normal mesh not created by the emmitter.

Comment: I  am not following you. 2.8 will have multiple Mesh edit https://www.blendernation.com/2018/05/04/blender-2-8-new-features-multi-object-edit/ is that what you mean?

Comment: I guess its not supported? I thought I could select multiple objects, hit S to scale and all selected objects scale at the same time. This worked in edit mode, but it was all hexagon and I couldn't limit my selection to say 8 and just scale those 8 selected.

Comment: in Object mode you can select n objects and then scale only those selected, make sure you have the origin set to Individual Origins.