# How to create randomly packed bed?

Tags: modeling

I can't find any tutorials "how to create randomly packed bed" in Blender. I need to create a randomly packed bed with help of rigid body dynamic model.

For example, I need to get a packed bed similar to a packed bed shown below:

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80690/random-sized-cylinders-with-no-intersection-gaps/

Answer (score 4):

What sort of difficulty have you met? To do this kind of thing:

- Create your cylinder, in the *Physics* panel press *Rigid Body*, choose *Type* > *Passive* and *Shape* > *Mesh*.
- Create your falling object, in the *Physics* panel press *Rigid Body*, choose *Type* > *Active*.
- Duplicate your object with <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> (linked duplication).
- Play the animation.

[image]