# Blender random packing animation (reactor cylinder type catalyst random packing)

Tags: rendering, particles, physics

I'd like to make an animation like bellow (reproduced from: DOI: 10.1016/j.cesx.2019.100006):
[image]

and I have tried to do referring the following sources:

[How to create randomly packed bed?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/138930/how-to-create-randomly-packed-bed/138933#138933?newreg=21f2b1b0ea4c4ec8a504ee17c518f546)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pexD2XhncNY

The following image is the results I have got, however, the pellets penetrate the corn and just free fall on the bottom.
even some pellets hang on the air.

How can I solve this?

[image]
The size of the main cylinder(actually reactor) is 1 in ID and 0.7 m length.
and the size of the pellet is 3mm diameter and 6 mm length.

Comment: Possibly inverted normals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your Steps Per Second high enough. This is in Scene tab under Rigid Body World and Settings. Default is 60 and seems to be too low in some cases. High value will slow down calculations but will be more accurate.

[image: Steps Per Second]

Next make sure your collision Shape is Mesh for you funnel. This is important for complex objects. For your pellets I think Capsule should be fine. Also make Sensitivity Margin small enough. Accurate shape will slow down calculations but will be more realistic.

[image: Collision Shape and Sensitivity Margin.]

Last make sure your walls are thick enough. If your wall are too thin then your particles can make through before next step happens.

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you for your kind help! I will try it!