# How to change material color in geometry nodes

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes, color

It is a very simple caveman geometry node setup.

I want to change the color of these bars as they rise [from black at lowest to orange at full scale]

[image]

[image]

and please explain in detail, how to control material from geometry nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To color geometry procedurally created inside a *Geometry Nodes* setup, you need to capture a certain attribute of that geometry and pass that information over to the shader nodes. Capturing part is usually done with a `Store Named Attribute` node. You then retrieve and manipulate the captured data inside the *Shader Editor* via an `Attribute` node. Do note that you also need to assign the relevant material to the geometry inside *Geometry Nodes* using a `Set Material` node--assigning a material the usual way, through the material window in the *Properties* panel is not sufficient.

In this first example, I'm capturing the `Instance Scale` information as a named attribute called '***i_s***', then accessing it in the shader nodes and converting it to color through a `ColorRamp`. Since scale is a singular value, I'm capturing it as *float*. Additionally, since I'm capturing this information in the *Instance* domain, I need to use the *Instancer* mode of the `Attribute` node:

[image]

This second setup is very similar. I'm still capturing *float* values in the *Instance* domain, but instead of their scales, I'm using the `Index` numbers of our instances. `ColorRamp` node only uses values within the $0-1$ range, so if my captured values contain smaller or larger values than that, mapping them to the $0-1$ range beforehand is a good idea. In your setup you have $2500$ instances, which means our index numbers go from $0$ to $2499$. I use a `Map Range` to fit that between $0-1$. I also use the *Constant* mode of the `ColorRamp` node so there's no interpolation between colors, just to demonstrate that it is an option:

[image]

Since we've been employing the *Instance* domain, our cylinders are colored one by one, as singular instances, regardless of their shape or number of faces--the whole cylinder is always just one color. You're not limited to that. If you `Realize Instances`, you get access to their internal, raw geometry: *vertices, edges, faces*. In this third example, after realizing the instances, I'm capturing the *Z* location of eeach *point* of our geometry, and using that information to color it. Notice that in the `Attribute` node we've switched to *Geometry* mode, and since the captured attribute is evaluated and converted to color between each and all points, cylinders can have multiple colors at the same time. Using the *B-Spline* mode of the `ColorRamp` also makes the interpolation between points more gradual.

[image]

A last example [from an older answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/280718/71578) below, where I'm coloring the sphere instances according to their distance to the outer capsule mesh they're located in:

[image]