# Instance 3D text on object with random rotation

Tags: modeling, modifiers, geometry-nodes

I'm struggling with a 3D design for a lighter case.
I have a cylindrical object and want to cover it with 3D text instances, each with **random rotations**. (while avoiding self-intersections, if possible.)

Any tips or techniques to achieve this efficiently?

This is how far I've come using the curve modifier, but I just can't find a way to make random rotations without doing it by hand individually.

[image]

EDIT: here's a image of how it should roughly look like:
[image]

Comment: can u pls show an image how the end result should be like? rotations can be in different ways...

Comment: @Chris hey I just updated my post to include that. hope this clarifies

Comment: wow ...ok...avoiding intersections isn't that easy.... :(

Comment: I think it would probably be easier to split out the problem of the non-intersecting randomly rotated scatter of your motif, in the flat. (It can be mapped onto the curved surface later.) The motif is a long,thin rectangle,  truly random rotations would result in a very sparse scatter.. maybe you're looking for imperfect packing? Maybe a rectangular version of [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/80721/35559) ?

Comment: @RobinBetts that’s a great idea! I’ll try that. Thanks