How to create repetitive coffee beans surface in relief?
I wish to create a silicone mold with a coffee beans relief, like this one:
https://i.etsystatic.com/21199693/r/il/2f6513/2640683730/il_1588xN.2640683730_i535.jpg

My knownledge in very limited (even more in nodes) and I'm having trouble disposing the beans more randomly, rotating them without deforming the beans and having a nice relief like on the picture. I also can't avoid having them overlay each other.
I managed to get this:

With these few nodes:

As you can see, the beans aren't randomly disposed enough, beans overlay each other and some empty spaces are present within the relief.
Could you help me get this nice relief surface?

Why do specifically need geometry nodes? Could be done with physics https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80690/random-sized-cylinders-with-no-intersection-gaps/

Those beans are close enough to sphere to use Poisson Disc distribution, but far enough from it that you can't stop there. So start with making your bean, then adding a geonodes modifier to it:

Grid size, Distance Min and Amount are things you probably will need to adjust to your bean size (the Distance Min should equal the largest diameter of the bean).
Apply the geonodes modifier.
Now create another object (cube), and add this modifier to it, to create a bounding box of your generated beans:

Apply this modifier too, then go to Edit Mode scale it up very slightly and remove the top face. Go to physics settings, and make it a passive rigid body with precise shape:

Now select your beans object, go to Edit Mode, A select all, ✲ CtrlP Separate by Loose Parts.
F3 Set origin to center of mass.
Go to physics settings, make the active bean an active rigid body, decrease its weight and collision margin to 0.001.
F3 Copy Rigid Body Settings (make sure other beans are still selected).
Play the simulation

with all beans selected, F3 Apply Transformation, and F3 Remove Rigid Bodies.
M New Collection, to add beans to a new collection.
This is the best moment to modify the beans arbitrarily.
Now you can add another cube, make scale it (in edit mode) to contain all beans, and add another geonodes modifier:

In Outliner, disable the beans collection visibility:

You may need to readjust the position of the form before boolean:

